# How can we store List<String> values in an Iterator like Iterator<List<String>>?

Tags: java, list, iterator

I need to store the values coming from a loop within a `Iterator<List<String>>`.
I tried a lot to find a way but couldn't find any.
Providing you the code.

```
ListIterator<List<String>> itrr = null;
        for (int i = startLoop; i <= endLoop; i++) {
            List<String> listOfString = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = startInnerLoop; j <= endInnerLoop; j++) {
                // for each cell we have to derive the row value as A1:A1
                String address = Number2Column.execute(j) + i;
                address += Constants.COLONSPLITTER + address;
                listOfString.add(executor.getSingleCell(false, address).get().toString());
            }
            itrr.add(listOfString);
        }
```

Here for a sake of try i used ListIterator to add the Collection but can it be type casted to 
`Iterator<List<String>>`?

Comment: Are you aware of the `List.listIterator()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterator does not store data. It is a representation of underlying collection that allows you to iterate over it.

Just store your list of strings in another list `List<List<String>>`. `List` class implements `Iterable` interface, that means you can get an iterator over any list.

```
List<List<String>> itrr = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = startLoop; i <= endLoop; i++) {
        List<String> listOfString = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = startInnerLoop; j <= endInnerLoop; j++) {
            ...
            listOfString.add(...);
        }
        itrr.add(listOfString);
}
Iterator<List<String>> iter = ittr.iterator();
```

You can even get `ListIterator` if you need to.

```
ListIterator<List<String>> listIter = ittr.listIterator();
```

Comment: Thankx @uaravan, I just did'nt try for the concept.